# What's the best way to show and hide parts of an MVC view based on some logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just have something I'm thinking about and something which I've been implementing in a lot of my code which I don't think is the best way of doing things.

You know, after you submit a form, you may want to direct back to the same page and display a success message and want to hide the submitted form inputs for example. Other times, you may direct to a page with an optional parameter, like a query string, and based on that parameter, you may want to show and hide certain things on your view.

I'm not sure the best way to do this because I like keeping all logic in my controller and not putting logic in my view.

You can accomplish this in webforms simply by separating your elements in different panels and setting the hidden property in your cs control.

The way I've been doing this in MVC (which I don't like) is, for example, with a ViewBag success message and an if statement in my view which checks if the viewbag is null. If it's not null, it displays the success message; else, it displays some form inputs. Other times, you don't use a viewbag. For example, a checkout page for a shopping cart. In your view, you might check if the cart model is empty. If it is, display a "sorry, your cart is empty" message; else, display the cart table. I don't like handling this with if logic in my view. What is the best solution? Is there another solution?

Some example code here.

Control:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(Elephants elephants)
 {
     // do something with elephants 

     ViewBag.weldone = "Weldone, you have made a wonderful impact by submitting this crucial knformation about elephants to the world";
     return View();

 }
```

View:

```
 @if(ViewBag.weldone != null)
 {
      <p>@ViewBag.weldone</p>
 }

 else
 {
      //something you want to hide from the page on succesfull elephant save

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ViewBag, use a view-model instead - its called "Model View Controller" for a reason.

```
public class Elephants
{
    ...
    public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Elephants model)
{
    // do something with elephants 

    model.SuccessMessage = "yay";
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model Elephants

@if (model.SuccessMessage != null)
{
   <p>@model.SuccessMessgae</p>
}
else
{
   // Redisplay Elephants
}

@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

OR you could avoid all that by redirecting to another page which displays your message.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Elephants model)
{
    // do something with elephants 

    return RedirectToAction("EditSuccess");
}

[HttpGet]
public ViewResult EditSuccess()
{
    return View();    // Displays view "EditSuccess.cshtml"
}
```